# What is the purpose of session pool_mode in pgbouncer?

Tags: postgresql, connection-pooling, pgbouncer

Since in this mode pgbouncer creates outbound connection for each inbound connection it seems to me that pgbouncer doesn't work as pooler.
It's just 1 to 1 mapping.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There would be 1 connection to the server for each connection to pgbouncer, but not necessarily a *new* connection. When a connection to pgbouncer is closed it doesn't close the connection to the server, just makes that connection available to the pool. Then when a new connection comes in, that pooled connection can be reused.

If the connections to pgbouncer are generally long-lived ones, this might not be of much benefit. But, if there are a lot of short connections, it could result in a major improvement.

There was an excellect [blog post](http://www.depesz.com/2012/12/02/what-is-the-point-of-bouncing/) published recently about pgbouncer, and the different modes of operation.